# Failed to instantiate , parameter bookTitle

Tags: reactjs, spring, kotlin

okay i am trying to send a file with 2 string objects using axios to my spring controller i am using the same variable names so i have no idea, why
i am getting this error

"Failed to instantiate [com.onlinelibrary.bookservice.dto.messages.Messages$AddBookRequestMessage]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.onlinelibrary.bookservice.dto.messages.Messages$AddBookRequestMessage., parameter bookTitle"

```
const ManageBooksTab = () => {

const [book, setBook] = useState()
const [bookTitle, setBookTitle] = useState('')
const [bookDescription, setBookDescription] = useState('')
const [addDisabled, setAddDisabled] = useState(true)
const [deleteDisabled, setDeleteDisabled] = useState(true)



const handleBookAddSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(book , bookTitle, bookDescription)

    const body = {
        bookTitle: bookTitle,
        bookDescription: bookDescription,
        bookFile: book
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:8989/books/add', body, APIService.config).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.warn('error during http call adding book', err);
        console.warn('error during http call adding book Response: ', err.response);
    });
}

const handleBookDeleteSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8989/books/delete/${e.target.value}`, APIService.config).then( response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.warn('error during http call deleting book', err);
        console.warn('error during http call deleting book Response: ', err.response);
    });
}

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setBook(e.target.value)
}

const handleDeleteSelection = (e) => {
    setDeleteDisabled(false)
}

const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

useEffect(e => {
    APIService.getAccessibleData()
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setBooks(response.data)
        }).catch(function (ex) {
        console.log('User Response parsing failed. Error: ', ex);
        console.log('User Response parsing failed. Error: Server Response', ex.response);
    });
}, [])

return (
    <>
        <Container className="col-5">
            <Form.Group controlId="formFileLg" className="mb-3">
                <Form.Label> <strong>Add Book</strong> </Form.Label>
                <br/>
                <Form.Label>Book Title</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="textfield" onChange={e => setBookTitle(e.target.value)} placeholder='Enter Title'/>
                <Form.Label>Book Description</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="textarea" onChange={e => setBookDescription(e.target.value)} placeholder='Enter Description'/>

                <Form.Label>Upload Book PDF</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="file" size="lg" onChange={e => {handleFileChange(e)}}/>
                <br/>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={(e) => handleBookAddSubmit(e)}>
                    Add Book
                </Button>
            </Form.Group>

            <hr/>
            <br/>
            <Form.Group controlId="formFileLg" className="mb-3">
                <Form.Label> <strong>Delete Book</strong> </Form.Label>
                <br/>
                <Form.Label>Select Book to delete</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control as="select">
                    {
                        books.map((bookIndex,index) => {
                            return (
                                <option value={bookIndex.id} key={index}>{bookIndex.bookTitle} : {bookIndex.id}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </Form.Control>
                <br/>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onChange={e => handleDeleteSelection(e)} onClick={(e) => handleBookDeleteSubmit(e)}>
                    Delete Book
                </Button>
            </Form.Group>
        </Container>
    </>
)
```

}

here's my controller method

```
    @PostMapping("/add")
@Throws(UserException::class, AWSException::class, AccessException::class, BookException::class)
fun addBook(
    @ModelAttribute message: AddBookRequestMessage,
    bindingResult: BindingResult
): ResponseEntity<BookAddResponseMessage> {
    bindErrorResult(bindingResult)
    return ResponseEntity.ok(bookService.addBook(message))
}
```

and the data class i am requesting from my react client

```
    data class AddBookRequestMessage(
    val bookTitle: String,
    val bookDescription: String,
    val bookFile: MultipartFile
)
```

i have no idea what i am doing wrong can anyone help me with this? and please feel free to ask if anything else is needed
PS i have tried my controller with form-data in postman and its working fine i have problem with react

Answer (score 0):

Hey i was just loading file in a wrong way here

```
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
setBook(e.target.value)
```

}

where it should be

```
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setBook(e.target.files[0])
}
```

also have to fetch data like this in form data

```
 const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('bookTitle', bookTitle)
    formData.append('bookDescription', bookDescription)
    formData.append('bookFile', book)


    axios.post('http://localhost:8989/books/add', formData, APIService.config).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.warn('error during http call adding book', err);
        console.warn('error during http call adding book Response: ', err.response);
    });
```